# Oozie workflow for sqoop import fails in Amazon emr hue

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, oozie, amazon-emr

I have created a oozie workflow to do the sqoop import from mysql to hive system.

My Sqoop job for creating a sqoop job runs successfully but when I try to execute a job to import from MySQL into Hive it fails. Here I attached the logs

The sqoop --hive-import (that is what the failing sqoop action does) happens in two steps.

1. First a sqoop import to the HDFS directory (targetDir referred in my xml).
2. Then the output of this sqoop import is moved and imported into Hive.

When I run my sqoop job through oozie I see a _SUCCESS file in targetDir indicating the sqoop import is successful. Only the later stage (step 2) is failing.

I am running the Oozie workflow as hue user.

```
9020 [uber-SubtaskRunner] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  - Loading uploaded data into Hive
9982 [Thread-112] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  - WARNING: Use "yarn jar" to launch YARN applications.
10278 [Thread-112] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  - SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
10278 [Thread-112] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  - SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
10278 [Thread-112] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  - SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
10278 [Thread-112] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  - SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
10281 [Thread-112] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  - SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
12413 [Thread-112] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  - 
12413 [Thread-112] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  - Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-common-2.1.0-amzn-0.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
13750 [Thread-112] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tez/dag/api/SessionNotRunning
13751 [Thread-112] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:586)
13751 [Thread-112] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:518)
13751 [Thread-112] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:705)
13751 [Thread-112] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
13751 [Thread-112] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
13751 [Thread-112] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
13751 [Thread-112] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
13751 [Thread-112] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
13751 [Thread-112] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
13751 [Thread-112] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
13751 [Thread-112] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  - Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tez.dag.api.SessionNotRunning
13751 [Thread-112] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
13751 [Thread-112] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
13751 [Thread-112] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
13751 [Thread-112] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
13751 [Thread-112] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  -    ... 10 more
14098 [uber-SubtaskRunner] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.tool.CreateHiveTableTool  - Encountered IOException running create table job: java.io.IOException: Hive exited with status 1
    at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeExternalHiveScript(HiveImport.java:389)
    at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeScript(HiveImport.java:339)
    at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.importTable(HiveImport.java:240)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CreateHiveTableTool.run(CreateHiveTableTool.java:58)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.runSqoopJob(SqoopMain.java:197)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.run(SqoopMain.java:177)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:47)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.main(SqoopMain.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler.runSubtask(LocalContainerLauncher.java:380)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler.runTask(LocalContainerLauncher.java:301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler.access$200(LocalContainerLauncher.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler$1.run(LocalContainerLauncher.java:230)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Intercepting System.exit(1)

<<< Invocation of Main class completed <<<

Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], exit code [1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because sqoop can't find hive.

Try setting env variable for hive in all of your datanodes on which user you are running this sqoop command

Edit:

type in command line

```
oozie admin -shareliblist hive
```

and check `tez-api-*.jar` is there.

if not, then go to hdfs path `/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_DATA/hive/` and check `tez-api-*.jar` is  there. if present then update sharelib `oozie admin -sharelibupdate` and check again

Comment: I set the HIVE_HOME in bashrc and refresh the properties but no luck. I mentioned in my sqoop job as well by setting --hive-home property. Other datanodes doesn't have hive folder in /etc/. Can you please point me to reference or elaborate your answer

Comment: have you added this too, "export HIVE=$HIVE_HOME/bin
export PATH=$HIVE:$PATH" and then type "exec bash"

Comment: the issue is because oozie will run the job in any of the datanodes, so you should install hive in all datanodes with configuration and then try again

Comment: Is there any solution from amazon emr end ? If I install Hive separately how the session is shared with the clusters

Comment: after installing hive, in conf you will be pointing to the same metastore

Comment: After installing and setting up the property it says hive-exec-*.jar is missing

Comment: when are you getting this error, when running sqoop action via oozie? can you elaborate

Comment: I am getting this via oozie. I am able to run sqoop job successfully by sshing into master node.

Comment: did you setup oozie sharelib -> https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/AG_Install.html#Oozie_Share_Lib it will contain hive-exec-*.jar

Comment: No luck @Nirmal Ram

Comment: have you added this property in oozie-site.xml pointing to sharelib in hdfs path <property>
        <name>oozie.service.WorkflowAppService.system.libpath</name>
        <value>/user/${user.name}/share/lib</value>
        <description>
            System library path to use for workflow applications.
            This path is added to workflow application if their job properties sets
            the property 'oozie.use.system.libpath' to true.
        </description>
    </property>

Comment: and in job.properties added oozie.use.system.libpath=true

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128815/discussion-between-hurix-and-nirmal-ram).

Comment: so the previous error got resolved on sqoop classnot found?

Comment: My previous question related to Oozie workflow only. I have tried to install Hive on slave nodes as per your suggestion. After that, I got into  Sqoop issue. Currently, that is solved

Comment: It doesn't help. Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop is unable to find Tez jar ( i.e. "org.apache.tez.dag.api.SessionNotRunning" class, to be exact ) during runtime.

Please verify if you have the Tez jars as required.

Comment: When I run the Sqoop job in the master node. It's running successfully because Tez is configured and I am able to access Hive in the master node. I am trying to execute Sqoop Job using Oozie Workflow which runs the Hive yarn MapReduce in slave nodes. When I try to launch hive in slave nodes, It says Tez session is not running though Hive & Tez configured properly.                                                                                                                Is that a limitation of Amazon EMR or am I missing any major configuration

Comment: @Hurix Did you try by adding tez-site.xml and necessary tez libraries.

Comment: @YoungHobbit Yes it is in place

Comment: @Hurix Please check this link:  http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/oozie/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a17_HDFS_Share_Libraries_for_Workflow_Applications_since_Oozie_2.3.

please check for hdfs shared lib. 
17 HDFS Share Libraries for Workflow Applications (since Oozie 2.3)

Comment: @Marco99 All the libraries are in place. I feel the issue is because of EMR clusters

Comment: @Hurix: It is not because of EMR cluster.
As you might know, the concept of hdfs shared library is to share the jars among the tasks run in the worker nodes. So i guess it should be a configuration issue.